# Hide Text and Add a Button to make it show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, greasemonkey

I'm trying to change a script, I'm doing this more to learn how to do it than because I need it.

Once you click a link on the page you got a javascript:nameoffunction('somekey');
So it pop ups on your screen. [The Script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121249) open that pop up on a blank part of the website, on the right side, at least is the intention.

So what I'm trying to do is hide the description text of the opened object with a button 'SHOW it' ,so the text would only appears when clicked.

I've tried use listeners onload,DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument nothing is working. I got undefined error for the element I try to input the button on the DOM

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="divlegenda" align="left">';

if (typeof contentWindow != 'undefined') {
    unsafeWindow = contentWindow; // google chrome
} else if (typeof unsafeWindow != 'undefined') {
    // firefox
} else {
    unsafeWindow = window; // opera + safari?
}

//unsafeWindow
unsafeWindow.abredown = function abredown(download) {
    document.getElementById('divlegenda').innerHTML = '<iframe src="info.php?d='+download+'" width="498" height="2500" frameborder="0" id="framelegenda"></iframe>';

}

description = document.getElementById('divlegenda').getElementsByClassName('comentuser')[0];
description.style.display='none';

button = document.createElement('button');
button.id = 'show';
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<< Show >>'));
button.onclick = function () { click(); };
document.getElementsByClassName('titulofilme')[2].appendChild(button);


function click() {
    description.style.display='inherit';
    button.style.display='none';
}
```

The HTML part where I try to insert

```
    <td class="titulofilme">
<div align="left">Comentário:</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="comentuser">
<div id="descricao" align="left">
...text here...
```

When I open source code on the page, the element inserted with id divlegenda cannot be found. I can only see it with inspect element when I right click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. Greasemonkey runs on iframes as though they were separate pages.  You must account for (or exploit) this when coding for pages where you care about iframed content.
2. Avoid using `innerHTML` as much as possible.  It will break things (events, etc.), it's slow, and if you are trying to write reusable code, it will behave differently across browsers.
   `document.body.innerHTML +=` is especially bad.
3. That's the wrong way to try and get cross-browser compatibility, and it won't work.  Also, `contentWindow` has been obsolete for many versions of Chrome.

   If the script is for more than one browser, say so in the question and tag appropriately.  This is tagged [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) -- which means that it is for Firefox or Tampermonkey (a Chrome extension).
   It's easiest and best to code in pure Greasemonkey style unless you've a darn good reason not to.
4. Step up to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it will make things so much easier.
5. Don't use attributes to style things (`width="498"`, `height="2500"`, etc.).  Use CSS.
6. When you open the page source (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>), it shows only the static HTML, you won't see stuff that the page, Greasemonkey, or Firebug has changed.  Use the inspection tools for that.
   **However**, if you ***save*** the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), Firefox will save the current DOM to disk, including changes made by the various scripts.

So without further explanation, here is a *Greasemonkey* script that does what the question specified:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Legendas.tv, show details in an iframe
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://legendas.tv/*
// @include     https://legendas.tv/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.top == window.self) {
    /*--- This part executes only in the master window (Not in iframes).
        It's not necessary in this case, just showing how...
    */
    //--- jQuery uses proper DOM methods to add nodes
    $("body").append ('<div id="divlegenda"></div>');

    unsafeWindow.abredown   = function abredown (download) {
        var legendaryDiv    = document.getElementById ('divlegenda');
        if (legendaryDiv) {
            //--- innerHTML is okay-ish here; replace later.
            legendaryDiv.innerHTML  = '<iframe src="info.php?d='
                                    + download + '"></iframe>';
        }
        window.scrollTo (0,0);
    }
}

/*--- This part executes both in frames and out. But the code (so far)
    is harmless if the targeted nodes are not present.
*/

//--- Hide comments but add a button to show them...
$(".comentuser").hide ().each ( function () {
    $(this).before ('<button class="gmShowHide"><< Show >></button>');
} );

//--- Activate the button(s).
$("button.gmShowHide").click ( function () {
    var jThis       = $(this);
    var Comments    = jThis.next ();
    Comments.toggle (); //-- Show or hide as necessary

    if (/Show/.test (jThis.text () ) )
        jThis.text ('>> Hide <<');
    else
        jThis.text ('<< Show >>');
} );


GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    #divlegenda {
        margin:             0;
        padding:            0;
        position:           fixed;
        top:                0;
        right:              0;
        height:             100%
    }
    #divlegenda iframe {
        margin:             0;
        padding:            0;
        width:              598px;
        height:             100%
        border:             none;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

Comment: 1. Thank you very much, specially for the comment lines.
2. Now I really know I need to study jQuery and CSS, which my knowledge is close to zero.
3. I'm really sorry, I've left the code that way. Since I'm not the author, I was just trying to edit the part I wanted to work.
4. Can I post this code on userscripts? Do you bother if I give you the credit for doing it?

Comment: Nothing to apologize for here, and of course you can post the code in userscripts. ... Credit is nice but not necessary.  However, if you link back to a SO post, and others follow that link, then you can get [some shiny badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64436/148310) for that.

Comment: Yesterday I was watching some videos of lynda.com jQuery essentials training, and it's amazing the things I can do, a lot more easier than javascript. I'll try to do some improvements and probably upload on userscripts later.

Comment: I'm having trouble to hide an ad that's why I didn't post the script yet. I've tried to hide it these days, but the ad only appears one time per day. So I have one shot per day and none of them worked so far. I'm almost giving up to remove it, because for me I can easily block it with firefox addon. I'd like to do it more for the users that would use the script. 10 seconds after page load, the ad appears and the close button has this code 
`code`parent.document.getElementById("advdoa").style.display = 'none';`code`

Comment: The style of the main div id "holder" change to block, and a new div id "advdoa" with a iframe appended "doafr" appears.
I've tried set their style to none into GM_addStyle.    
`code`$("#advdoa").hide();         

And yesterday I've tried:     
`code`waitForKeyElements ("#advdoa", hideShit, true, "#doafr");
function hideShit (jNode) {
  jNode.css ("style", "none");
}`code`          

and Today:
`code`waitForKeyElements ("#advdoa", hideShit");
function hideShit (jNode) {
  jNode.css ("style", "none");
}`code`
      
And to try tomorrow:
`code`function hideShit (jNode) {
 jNode.hide();
}`code`

Comment: This looks like a different problem; Please open a new question for it.  It's a right pain trying to solve stuff from comments -- especially when more than a few characters of code are posted/needed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait tomorrow and if the last code don't work I'll open a new question.

Comment: Fortunately the last code worked, hid it. I'll wait one more day to make sure. You're right, it really sucks see the code in comments. If something goes wrong I'll post a new question. Sorry to any inconvinient.